# Java - Concatenate String with method name

Tags: java, object, arraylist, concatenation

As you can see in this post title I have a silly question... However I wonder if there is more efficient way to deal with this kind of programming scenario that I am facing. I am programming with **Java** and I have created the following Class:

```
public class Route {
    private String objective_1;
    private String objective_2;
    ...

    // CONSTRUCTOR__________________________________________________________________________________

    public Route() {
    }

    public Route(String objective_1, String objective_2, ...) {;
        this.objective_1 = objective_1;
        this.objective_2 = objective_2;
        ...
    }

    // GET AND SET__________________________________________________________________________________

    public String getObjective_1() {...}

    public void setObjective_1(String objective_1) {...}

    public String getObjective_2() {...}

    public void setObjective_2(String objective_2) {...}

    ...
}
```

Next (in the main class) I create objects from the **Route Class** and save them in an **Arraylist** (array_routes). Later I try to get and print all objectives from the object on the 0 index of the Arraylist. I am using this code:

```
System.out.println(array_routes.get(0).getObjective_1);
System.out.println(array_routes.get(0).getObjective_2);
...
```

Now comes the silly question... I have 28 objectives in the Route Class. What I intend to do is to have a more efficient approach to print all object objectives. **Instead of writing 28 get Objective methods (like in the previous code) I wonder if I can do something like this:**

```
for (int j = 1; j < 29 ; j++) {
    String jj = String.valueOf(j);
    System.out.println(array_routes.get(0).getObjective_+"jj");
}
```

I know that the previous code doesn't work... But does anyone know an efficient way to not write 28 get Objective methods? Is this even possible?

**Thanks in advance for your time and hopefully for your help too!**

Comment: Use a data structure like a `Map` to achieve your logic.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. Better to put all the objectives in a collection, an ArrayList if indexed by number, or a Map if indexed by String or other type, and then simply loop through when needed.

Comment: I don't like to suggest it but the solution you are looking for can be achieved with reflection - but it's actually not good coding practice to treat your route as a dumb data container but you should rather design a route as a meaningful object which e.g. could have a print method itself.

Comment: I will research your suggestions! Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: @Smutje then why did you suggest it? Using reflection to achieve dynamic programming capabilities with Java just causes problems. Especially with beginners who may understand it as a "normal" part of the Java toolset.

Comment: Reflection is a powerful tool, use it only if there is nothing else. You can easily open a can of worms with it.

Comment: Thumb of rule: if your method name contains a digit, then you need to think twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(1, 29).forEach(i->{
            Method method = output.getClass().getMethod("getFillerLibre"+ String.valueOf(i));
            method.invoke(output);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case for advanced enum usage. Then you have names for your objectives, and can deal with maps, sets and subsets.

```
enum Objective { OBJIVE1, OBJECTIVE2, ... }

EnumMap<Objective, String> objectives = new EnumMap<>(Objective.class);
```

Reflection is a crutch and slow, so give an API redesign a chance.